# How to get nearest cities with Google Nearby API?

Tags: api, google-nearby, google-geolocation

I'm working in a project where I should display all cities (locality) around 20km from a device location using lat,long.

Moreove, the locality of the device location is not on the result.

Could someone help me?

I precise that I'm not a developer.

Many thanks for your help!

I tried the request below on Postman, but I only have two results rather than more than 10.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.7707452,2.0803735&radius=20000&type=locality&key=AIzxxxxxxE

Below is the response:

`

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 48.801408,
                    "lng": 2.130122
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 48.82857804347341,
                        "lng": 2.168480543860636
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 48.77916591232869,
                        "lng": 2.069908968772275
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "Versailles",
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 3024,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116593793480207812084\">Jessy Velazquez</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AUjq9jkmbt7CKGCwJfn3ZlpLVC-wGt_1svXYWTyA5p9pgcmd6XCNbEcwAFFjF0xe2tuLIYm5F_42s0Q4dbI0ifJTHZy5-gfzQfSo2jMp_ATL-WfPl3jJHf8WbnRVLSslBCKg3j5jYQBU2pkyb2Tjkk7PLZSGSuv9ycLQu-j2zTBWUM9x-ejT",
                    "width": 4032
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJvSD0dbR95kcRukqEDa0AnoY",
            "reference": "ChIJvSD0dbR95kcRukqEDa0AnoY",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ],
            "vicinity": "Versailles"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 48.7738734,
                    "lng": 2.0360157
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 48.7992215538692,
                        "lng": 2.055979168810353
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 48.75589319907799,
                        "lng": 1.994393632933018
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "Montigny-le-Bretonneux",
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 4160,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100080658394344210444\">ali imoune</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AUjq9jn0-yeBGJe57tERWIrudEEdhV_zdqrrtGna1VvH-vI33q2FMfh7c_YaZpK4VXR1eWFhU7MYt0rhxZujTMnM3DL7F5vOXX0zepVThDaB_I5gZ0Io2RjnXbYh4ZDInZ-0aXDY-w4xdisBO_4oAAVgot1516GAbE-He8jvgCacDUcp03w1",
                    "width": 3120
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJDxMIwS-B5kcRHthZxYnQcNo",
            "reference": "ChIJDxMIwS-B5kcRHthZxYnQcNo",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ],
            "vicinity": "Montigny-le-Bretonneux"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

### `type=locality` is not supported by Nearby Search of Places API

Please see [Place Types Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types).

As you can see on the documentation, the `types=locality` is only available in **Table 2 and 3**:

> The Place type values in Table 2 are used in the following ways:
>
> - As part of the result of a Place details request (for example, a call to fetchPlace()), or anywhere a Place result is returned. The request must specify the appropriate "types" [data field](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-data-fields).
> - As part of an Autocomplete place prediction. For more information on the rules for using these values, see [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete).
> - To denote address components.

ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table2

There's a note there that such types are **not supported** in the `type` filter of a place search.

This begs us the question...

### How to get the nearest cities?

To be able to get nearby cities using Places API, you can use the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete) of Places API.

The Place Autocomplete also have the `types`, `radius`, and `location` parameters that you can use just like the [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby).

But since Place Autocomplete is designed to respond to **user input** and requires an `input` parameter, your users still needs to put something before sending a request.

Here's an example request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?
input={INPUT_ANY_CITY_HERE_WITHIN_20KM_OF_LOCATION}
&location=48.7707452,2.0803735
&radius=20000
&strictbounds=true
&types=(cities)
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

> ***Note**: I included `strictbounds` to return only those places that are strictly within the region defined by location and radius. This is a restriction, rather than a bias, meaning that results outside this region will not be returned even if they match the user input.*

The request will only return cities within the circle of this sample map:

```js
function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat:48.7707452, lng: 2.0803735},
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });

    const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: {lat:48.7707452, lng: 2.0803735},
      radius: 20000, 
    });
  }

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Circles</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises.
      See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api
      for more information.
      -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I mean it works but it's totally useless, you need to input all the cities to get the names of the cities 